# Alcatel OS6860E ethernet ssh

Tags: switch, ssh

I set up on an Alcatel OS6960E (via console cable) a VLAN 99 with ip addr 192.168.164.33. My laptop ethernet ip is 192.168.164.29.

I connected my laptop to ethernet port 1/1/1 assigned to VLAN 99 but I can't ping or ssh to 192.168.164.33. What am I doing wrong?

The commands I used are:

```
vlan 99 name "IP management"
vlan 99 members port 1/1/1 untagged
ip interface vlan_99_ip address 192.168.164.33
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Alcatel equipment, but is it normal that you don't input a subnet mask or prefix length with the IP address? Also did you check that interface vlan99 is up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable or disable the administrative status for an existing VLAN, enter 
vlan
 followed by an existing 
VLAN ID and either 
enable
 or 
disable

> --> vlan 99 enable

Give this a go and see if that works. It's worth checking the status of the VLAN interface and make sure it isn't down. I got this from the configuration guide [here](http://enterprise.alcatel-lucent.com/assets/documents/os_nt_664_revD1.pdf) on page 112.

Hope this helps you on your quest.

SleepyMan

Answer (score 2):

You missed the `vlan NNN` statement at the end of the last line. Your `vlan_99_ip` is the mnemonic name of the L3 switch interface. It can't be assigned to the vlan 99 automatically.

You config should be like this

```
vlan 99 name "IP management"
vlan 99 members port 1/1/1 untagged
ip interface vlan_99_ip address 192.168.164.33 mask 255.255.255.0 vlan 99 admin enable
```

BTW, the command `show ip interface` show you which vlan your interface is bound to. For example:

```
-> show ip interface
Total 4 interfaces
        Name            IP Address     Subnet Mask   Status Forward  Device
--------------------+---------------+---------------+------+-------+--------
HJHJH                0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0           DOWN      NO unbound
Loopback             127.0.0.1       255.0.0.0           UP      NO Loopback
MGMT                 10.0.0.101      255.255.255.0     DOWN      NO vlan 200
VLAN-355             192.168.1.15    255.255.255.0       UP     YES vlan 355
```